# ¿como hacer un text-truncate de 2 líneas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

En algunos casos de mi pantalla, dependiendo del dispositivo, no se alcanza a ver el título completo de lo que escribo, se ve así:
`TITULO 1 TIT....` Aquí quedaría ya incompleto debido al text-truncate, y si lo quito, entonces se va a ver una imagen más grande que la otra.

¿Hay forma de que se pueda poner un text-truncate de 2 líneas?
Estuve mirando, dicen que con un:

```
.text-truncate p {
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

se arreglaría, pero la verdad es que sigue igual. Incluso allí está agregado eso al proyecto, pero no, se ve igual.

No sé si haya otra forma de que si un texto es más grande que el otro se vean en las mismas posiciones las imágenes, y llegado el caso (el text-truncate), que no aparezcan los *...* sino que haga un salto de línea abajo y se vea parejo para todos.

```css
body,
html {
  font-family: burbank2;
  text-align: center;
}

a,
p {
  text-align: center;
}

.titulo {
  font-family: burbank1;
}

/*CCS BODY*/
article {
  text-align: center;
}

/* responsive xs */
@media screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  img {
    text-align: center;
    width: 130px;
    height: 183px;
  }

  a {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

/* responsive sm */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  img {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 282px;
  }
}

/* responsive md */
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  img {
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    height: 353px;
  }
}

/* responsive lg */
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  img {
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    height: 353px;
  }
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.text-truncate p {
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <header class="titulo">
         <a href="https://web.com">WEB.COM</a>
      </header>
      <br>
      <div>
         <p>
            <a href="https://web.com">WEB</a>
         </p>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="col-12 text-truncate">
                  <a href="https://web.com/"> TITULO 1 TITULO 1 TITULO 1<br><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FJFCZvN/Img-Mesa-de-trabajo-1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="col-12 text-truncate">
                  <a href="https://web.com/"> TITULO 1 TITULO 1 TITULO 1<br><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FJFCZvN/Img-Mesa-de-trabajo-1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="col-12 text-truncate">
                  <a href="https://web.com/"> TITULO 1 TITULO 1 TITULO 1<br><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FJFCZvN/Img-Mesa-de-trabajo-1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="col-12 text-truncate">
                  <a href="https://web.com/"> TITULO 1 TITULO 1 TITULO 1<br><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FJFCZvN/Img-Mesa-de-trabajo-1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="col-12 text-truncate">
                  <a href="https://web.com/"> TITULO 1 TITULO 1 TITULO 1<br><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FJFCZvN/Img-Mesa-de-trabajo-1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="col-12 text-truncate">
                  <a href="https://web.com/"> TITULO 1 TITULO 1 TITULO 1<br><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FJFCZvN/Img-Mesa-de-trabajo-1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="col-12 text-truncate">
                  <a href="https://web.com/"> TITULO 1 TITULO 1 TITULO 1<br><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FJFCZvN/Img-Mesa-de-trabajo-1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="col-12 text-truncate">
                  <a href="https://web.com/"> TITULO 1<br><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FJFCZvN/Img-Mesa-de-trabajo-1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="col-12 text-truncate">
                  <a href="https://web.com/"> TITULO 1 TITULO 1 TITULO 1<br><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FJFCZvN/Img-Mesa-de-trabajo-1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="col-12 text-truncate">
                  <a href="https://web.com/"> TITULO 1<br><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FJFCZvN/Img-Mesa-de-trabajo-1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="col-12 text-truncate">
                  <a href="https://web.com/"> TITULO 1 TITULO 1 TITULO 1<br><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FJFCZvN/Img-Mesa-de-trabajo-1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="col-12 text-truncate">
                  <a href="https://web.com/"> TITULO 1<br><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FJFCZvN/Img-Mesa-de-trabajo-1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="col-12 text-truncate">
                  <a href="https://web.com/"> TITULO 1<br><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FJFCZvN/Img-Mesa-de-trabajo-1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="col-12 text-truncate">
                  <a href="https://web.com/"> TITULO 1 TITULO 1 TITULO 1<br><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FJFCZvN/Img-Mesa-de-trabajo-1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
               <div class="col-12 text-truncate">
                  <a href="https://web.com/"> TITULO 1<br><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FJFCZvN/Img-Mesa-de-trabajo-1.png" class="img-responsive"> 
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```